# Capitalize the first letter of each word while typing in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7, capitalization

How do I capitalize the first character of each word while typing in Drupal 7?

I mean, while creating a node and entering the **node title**, while typing something it capitalizes the first character of each word.

I know that it does this capitalization with JavaScript and I found some JavaScript function like that:

```
function ucFirstAllWords( str )
{
    var pieces = str.split(" ");
    for ( var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++ )
    {
        var j = pieces[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        pieces[i] = j + pieces[i].substr(1);
    }
    return pieces.join(" ");
}
```

How do I apply this on Drupal for example on page.tpl.php file and/or for CCK fields.

**NOTE 1**: I don't want to use css, because it's just for display.

**NOTE 2**: I don't want to use PHP ucwords() because it doesn't affect database saving.

Some more info about what I do not want to use:

- I don't want to use PHP function `ucwords()`, I have to use PHP because it's Drupal.
- I don't want to use CSS because what CSS does is display change, it doesn't change the actual value. And I don't want to use the `ucwords()` function because it doesn't affect the database. If I use `ucwords()`, yes it works on display (on html page) but it doesn't work for database saving. If I type '*heLLo world*' it shows '*Hello World*' but in database it stored as it typed '*heLLo world*'.

Comment: If you don't want to use php, why tag the question with php ??

Comment: Your notes don't make a lot of sense to me, if it is just for display, you should use css. The second one I just don't get.

Comment: if you apply `ucwords()` before putting the data  in to the db, then wouldn't that work ?

Comment: @herci That totally depends on where you use `ucwords()`, on the input or on the output...

Comment: @Dagon I tried this and I'm still trying to find where to put this function, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what is NOT clear in this question (= the reason why it got closed). I hope my additions via the most recent (suggested) edit are sufficient to get this question voted to be reopened ... Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 2):

Why do it with PHP or JS? Just use plain CSS:

```
.text_element { text-transform:capitalize; }
```

Comment: I agree even though he said not to use css

Comment: @Dragon, I mean, OP can add that class and `echo` the text with PHP, no problem there.

Comment: not allowed php either !

Comment: now that he has changed the question, this does not apply ;(

Comment: @Dagon no, I didn't changed the question.

Comment: you really did, no one was interpreting it in the way its now asked.

Comment: @Dagon, I really couldn't understand what do you mean. The question is not edited or changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better approach is to simply try some *clientside validation* modules.
Examples:

- https://drupal.org/project/fapi_validation
- https://drupal.org/project/field_validation

Comment: Thanks, I have already used Field Validation module but it validates. If a user doesn't type 'the right' thing, it just doesn't accept not convert the value.